# Give Apache and Account User File Writing Priviliges

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, user-accounts, privileges, chown

I am using OS X Mountain Lion for web development. I am running the built-in Apache server. Now I need to allow the PHP script I am running to write in a directory. But if I `chown` the directory to `_www`, then the editor I am using, which is being used with the logged in user's account, is then unable to edit/write those files. So it's either the `_www` that can write to the directory or the `user`.

So how shall I go about solving this?

Answer (score 0):

Under OSX you can assign previleges to multiple users using the ACL. It can be accessed though Finder or its `chmod` implementation (`+a` option).

Or you can use the usual UNIX way where you create a group and put both your user and the apache user into it and make the group the group owner of the folder and `chmod -R g+rw` if necessary.